# How does the "Used by" feature work on GitHub?

Tags: javascript, github, npm, package.json

I was looking at many projects that show off a used by metric of how many other projects currently use or depend on a repo. It was really interesting but I did not find any information on how exactly it works.

From a little bit of reading up, I think this might have to do with the dependency graph. I am assuming that GitHub scans some sort of package manager configurations such package.json or composer.json to form the dependency graph. This may help in the used by feature.

However, I was also wondering how this would work in cases where package managers are not used.

It would be great if you can point me out to resources that help me understand this better as well as help me design projects that can make better use of the "Used by" feature.